# Strapi overrides database environment variables set in 'database.json' config file (is this a firewall issue?)

Tags: node.js, database, environment-variables, localhost, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to migrate Strapi CMS from Desktop (db formerly hosted with docker-mariadB) to a production server / VPS.

The database is hosted on shared hosting now (I'm able to connect from my desktop).

I have updated the `database.json` file as mentioned in [their documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/configurations/configurations.html#database). (now containing my database credentials that are working on desktop).

**The problem:**
When starting strapi, it gives me the following error: "Couldn't connect to myDBname@localhost".

I thought: Maybe outgoing connections aren't allowed, so maybe allow them?
I tried to `ufw allow` the database port for incoming and outgoing connections (tcp). This didn't work

I wouldn't know where to start searching for solutions. Therefore I hope you could help me direct me in the right direction ;)

Thanks in advance for taking your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a **^** in my password, therefore the host was set to 'localhost' automatically (because the connection couldn't be established).